# Create NSArray with specific property

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` called carparkArr that contain `MyCarpark` objects. This class contain:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate locationCoord;
```

Now I want to create an array that will have `NSValue` of each of these objects. How to do it quickly? I want something like:

```
NSArray *carparkArr = // fetching data
NSArray *locationProperty = [self getArrayForPropertyPath:@".locationCoord" forArray:carparkArr];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that feature already exists:

```
NSArray *locationProperty = [carparkArr valueForKey:@"locationCoord"];
```

Comment: Is that CLLocationCoordinate is a structure isn't a problem? NSArray cannot handle not NSObject elements.

Comment: @Szu KVC will wrap it automatically within an `NSValue` or `NSNumber` object.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think Foundation framework is so smart!